# MATLAB fitgmdist: Verbose Mode?

Tags: matlab, gaussian

I am using MATLAB's `fitgmdist` ("fit a guassian mixture to data", from the Statistics and Machine Learning Toolbox) with some success.  Is there a way to make it run in a verbose mode, e.g., tell me what iteration it is on, or show convergence stats during the process, so I know how well it is progressing?

Related, is there a way after the function has run and delivered the `gmdistribution` object, to determine how many iterations actually ran or how close the convergence came?  (It would be useful to know these things so I could better set the options parameters up front.)

Answer (score 0):

Simply put: no and yes.

You can try to access the actual .m-file (e.g. `open(fitgmdist)`) to copy it and then edit it to your purposes (copy it so you won't overwrite the build-in function), but there is no straight-forward implemented way to obtain the verbosity you want. The `name-value` pair which comes closest to what you want is `display`, `iter`:

> `iter`: Display iterative output to the Command Window for some functions; otherwise display the final output.

I am not quite sure about this part, since I can't run a test, but the final number of iterations should be available in the `gmdistribution` structure under `gmdistribution.NumIterations`. The [docs](http://mathworks.com/help/stats/gmdistribution-class.html) state that this is only for objects constructed with `fitgmdist`.